# Rotate images in header based on date

Tags: headers, header-image

I am new to WordPress and I would appreciate some cool advice here.

I have changed the `header.php` file in the Editor to include an image. I wonder if it is possible to automatically display one of 9 possible images depending on the date (ie. rotate them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will cycle between the 9 pics. 1st day of the year = pic0, 2nd = pic1...359th = pic9, 360th = pic0, etc.

```
<?php
$pic_array = array(
    'pic0',
    'pic1',
    'pic2',
    'pic3',
    'pic4',
    'pic5',
    'pic6',
    'pic7',
    'pic8',
);

$d = (int) date('z') % 9;
$todays_pic = $pic_array[$d];
echo $todays_pic;
```

Hopefully you're not changing a parent theme's header.php!

Comment: Thanks ! Although it is probably not a perfect rotation, since on 31 of a month it will display image #4 and on the next day it will display image #1, however, it works for me. What do you mean "Hopefully you're not changing a parent theme's header.php!" ?

Comment: Actually, my code rotation is based on the days of the ***year***. So excess repeats will only occur on pic0-pic6 once per year, e.g, day 365 will be pic6 then day 1 will roll back to pic0 (but you probably won't be using same setup that long!) RE: not changing parent theme's header.php, soon as you update (on purpose, or by mistake) you'll lose any cusomizations. See the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) on making child themes, pretty painless. There's even a [plugin to automate it](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/one-click-child-theme/) for you.

Comment: The reason I made it based on the year instead of the month is because of February. 28th would be pic0 and so would March 1st. If we were in March right now I probably would've used by month instead. :)